# Python pthread_detach analog

Tags: python, pthreads, detach

Good evening, everyone. I'm writing multithread program using Python 2.7 and *threading* module. Here is a code example:

```
# Importing myFunc function which will be run in the new thread
from src.functions import myFunc
# Importing a threading module
import threading
# Creating and running new thread initiated by our function
# and some parameters.
t = threading.Thread(target=myFunc, args=(1, 2, 3))
t.start()
```

I know that in C++ (POSIX thread libraries) there is a [pthread_detach()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html) function which puts a running thread in the detached state. It guarantees that this thread will release resources back to the system after the function ends. So, is there any analog of such function in Python? Or, maybe, it's not necessary to detach threads in Python at all, and the resources taken by the thread will be released automatically after the end of the threaded function?

I tried to search for information on [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) and Google but it was fruitlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Goog morning, everyone. Actually answer is *'it's not necessary to detach threads in Python at all'*. This answer was given to me by comrade *GaiveR* from [there](http://python.su/forum/topic/20403/). All you need is looking into source code of Python (thread_pthread.h):

```
long
PyThread_start_new_thread(void (*func)(void *), void *arg)
{
...
    status = pthread_create(&th,
#if defined(THREAD_STACK_SIZE) || defined(PTHREAD_SYSTEM_SCHED_SUPPORTED)
                         &attrs,
#else
                         (pthread_attr_t*)NULL,
#endif
                         (void* (*)(void *))func,
                         (void *)arg
                         );

#if defined(THREAD_STACK_SIZE) || defined(PTHREAD_SYSTEM_SCHED_SUPPORTED)
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);
#endif
    if (status != 0)
    return -1;

    pthread_detach(th);
...
}
```

Comment: It is not so simple. Are you sure the code is actually used by the interpreter (see comment at the top of [`Python/thread.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8a6068ec220e/Python/thread.c#l2) (the only place where `thread_pthread.h` is used))? As far as I understand `pthread_detach()` makes the thread unjoinable, but threads created with `threading.Thread()` *are* joinable.

Comment: @j-f-sebastian You are comparing apples with oranges here: ``pthread_detach`` makes the underlying system thread unjoinable, which has nothing to do with the join method of ``threading.Thread``, so you can't conclude pthread_detach is not called. In fact, Python preferably uses pthreads on Unix where available (it is on Linux), and the only call to ``pthread_create`` in Python 2.7 sources is in that function, so the answer is correct. [Join in Python](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.10/Lib/threading.py#l911) does not use pthread_join and does not provide a return value of the thread.